# gcc 5.2 install on mac 10.11

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

A little background, I'm currently trying to use ModFlow 2005 on my Mac and that means I needed to install gcc and Xcode. I have tried a few things, but honestly I'm pretty helpless when it comes to this because I have taken any programming classes.

I was able to install Xcode and Homebrew, but I haven't been able to find a tutorial that shows me how to install gcc 5.2. Is there an easier way for me to use install Mudflow 2005?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Homebrew, you can run `brew install gcc` from your terminal application.